# Wix burn skip package in chain

Tags: wix, burn

Is there a way to skip one of package in chain? I have looked at "InstallCondition" and have code like this.

```
                      <ExePackage Id="RoboMongo"
                        DisplayName="RoboMongo"
                        Cache="no"
                        Compressed="no"
                        PerMachine="yes"
                        Permanent="no"
                        Vital="no"
                        Name="redist\Robomongo-0.8.4-RC2-i386.exe"
                        DownloadUrl="$(var.RoboMongoUrl)"
                        InstallCondition="ComponentSelect_5"
                        InstallCommand='/Action=Install'
                        UninstallCommand="/Action=Uninstall"
                        RepairCommand ="/Action=Repair"
                        DetectCondition="RoboMongoInstalled">

            <RemotePayload Description="Программа администрирования MongoDB"
            Version ="0.8.4.2"
                ProductName="RoboMongo"
                Hash="71C17E48BC32304FA8724FFA7CA1C4C08891BC97" Size="7141182" />
```

But i don't want to uninstall it on InstallCondition=false. I just want to skip it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using managed bootstrapper application, required behavior can be achieved by handling PlanPackageBegin event. Code would look approximately like this:

```
    public MainViewModel(BootstrapperApplication bootstrapper)
    {
        bootstrapper.PlanPackageBegin += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["ShouldSkipPackage"] == "1")
                if (args.PackageId == "RoboMongo")
                    args.State = RequestState.None;
        };
    }
```

Comment: Is there also a clean way to skip a package for the default Bootstrapper application? If not could the 'skip' be delegated to the MSI? In my case I need to prevent an upgrade on a bundles MSI by cmdline parameter.